# Stick footer at the bottom, both if the content div is shorter or longer than window height

Tags: html, css, footer

There are many questions about this already, but I found no question that addresses this fully, nor an answer.

I have 3 divs:

```
<div id="header">
  Header
</div>
<div id="content">
  Content
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

I want:

1. the `footer` to always stick to the bottom of the page.
2. the `footer` to be at the bottom of the window if the size of all 3 divs together is smaller than the window height.
3. if there is enough stuff in the `content` `div` to make the entire page higher than the window height, the page should expand, but not in a way where the footer covers and hides part of the content.

I've seen answers which address 2 or 3, but not both.

Thank you.

Comment: actually what u want to do? I cann't understand you.

Comment: I want to have a page with a header, content and footer, such that the footer is always sticked at the bottom of the page, irregardless of how much content there is on the page AND I don't want the footer to be rendered over the content (so that it hides it). Is there something specific you didn't understand in my question?

Comment: Be careful with the title of your post. It's not about the window width, it's about the window height. And I believe a word is missing in the title to (after "or").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I present to you [the CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com)!

Go read and learn the code. It's pretty powerful and does exactly what you described.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. :{D

Answer (score 1):

Try this style. Hope this is what you want.

```
#header
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer
{        
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want to do, but it does not do 2 things - first, it does not expand the `"content"` `div` all the way down to the footer if the entire page is shorter than the window height. Second, if the content does not fit the area between the header and the footer, only the `"content"` area is scrolled - and the footer is always at the bottom of the *window*, whereas I want the footer to be at the bottom of the *page*. Could this be helped?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium mque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">Fixed FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{width:100%; background:#FFFFFF; font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px;}
#main{width:960px; margin:0 auto; background:#999999;}
#header{width:reminder; background:#0000FF; height:60px; padding:20px;}
#content{width:reminder; background:#CCC; color:#333333; padding:50px;}
#footer{width:940px; position:fixed; bottom:0; background:#000; color:#fff; padding:10px;}
```

Guess it helps you.